After Oracle Linux upgrade, getting "PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused"
After upgrading a server from Oracle Linux 7 to Oracle Linux 8 via leapp, one of our users who will use X sessions for testing and DB management is getting a message when he logs in of "PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused"  I didn't do anything with the X server, and he is the only person getting this message. Any ideas on where to start to get rid of this error?

Like RedHat 8 on which it is based, OracleLinux 8 by default uses Wayland instead of X.org, but your user can switch back to X.org at login time
